# Proper font size for each paper size for reader to be able to read names?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, design, font, text

I am working on a project that I need to figure it out how or what font size for each paper size. There are 10 of them and two of them are in the same paper size. There is data frame I have set aside to display the crop name as a Index and need to display their names to idenfity them.

- 60 x 34
- 56 x 52
- 43 x 50
- 62 x 66
- 56 x 74

I am trying to put down all the crop names  for each polygon, for example here, [image: Text name for each polygon].

I understand that it will be very diffcult to fill all the text names for each polygon for each paper size.  This one is the paper size 56 x 74.

I am curious if the reader would be able to read each font size at that kind of paper size? Any suggestions for me to tweak or fix them?

Comment: Quick clarification: when we're saying 56 x 74, I assume that is cm, not inches?

Comment: Erica,  oops yes they are in inches.

Comment: There are some other Stack Exchange sites that you may want to consider for this question.  For example, I found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126566/how-to-choose-font-size-given-the-paper-size and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35797/calculate-ideal-font-size-so-text-can-fit-into-cell.

Answer (score 2):

I found what looks to be a useful PDF entitled [Typography and readability](http://papunet.net/selkokeskus/fileadmin/tiedostot/muut/Itkonen.pdf) by Markus Itkonen.

Among much other interesting reading therein, he says in a section titled *Font Size*:

> There is no universally applicable guideline for font size. Choices in
>   this respect depend on such aspects as column width, clarity and
>   proportions of the typeface and the age of the intended readers.
>
> As one common saying regarding font size goes: Amateurs use too big
>   font sizes and professionals too small. It is clear that 12 points,
>   which is the default size in word processing programs, is too big for
>   normal printed material – with the exception of publications for
>   special groups. On the other hand, especially young graphic designers
>   often use an unnecessarily small font size. 8 points can be enough for
>   the person who has designed the typography but not for a reader who is
>   30 years older. The task of the graphic designer is not to test how
>   small a print the readers can read but to make the reading experience
>   as pleasant as possible. The use of too small a font size may also
>   indicate that the designer doesn’t consider the text and its careful
>   layout important but sees it rather as an uninteresting module that
>   ought not to interfere with the pictures and other graphics in the
>   publication.